# Mate DE Seems to have been broken by NVIDIA update

Tags: nvidia, crash, mate-desktop

So, I just installed the latest edition of Nvidia 495 on my system, independent of any other upgrades. (I upgraded my kernel to version 5.4.0-92 beforehand, but that seemed to be working fine.) Now, I can log in to KDE and XFCE, but Mate dumps me back to the login prompt immediately and unceremoniously.

The problem is likely something stupid, but I'm honestly at a loss as to what to even look for. Does Mate have a specific error file somewhere, or something I can do to find out what caused it to crash and how to fix it? (I prefer not to switch drivers, as my profession involves a heavy amount of multimedia programming and having that up-to-date driver is kind of critical.)

I thought about journalctl or systemctl, but I'm really not sure what to grep for here.

UPDATE: I've been digging in journalctl, and have confirmed that Xorg crashed, preceded by mintreport-tray. There's a trace beginning in libglib. All the related stacks are in the middle of a __GI__poll call. I'm still not certain what this means to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recent bug with MATE and the latest NVIDIA drivers 495.

https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-desktop/issues/505

Looks like someone has already figured out a patch for Xorg, but I would highly recommend to not patch Xorg manually, unless this is critical. The github issue also contains forum posts from nvidia, where they have opened a bug internally and people have the same issue. As far as I know 495 was beta not long ago.

Comment: Thanks, this is kind of what I was hoping to hear. I'll wait for Maté to release a formal and tested patch. I'm cozying up to KDE now anyway...